# How to boot copied partition

Tags: mount, partition, ubuntu-12.04, boot

I have just ghosted an Ubuntu (12.04) instance from a 200GB HD to a 1TB HD. The ghosted instance has two mounted storage partitions both of about 100GB each and I have the following partition table:

```
Partition      File System      Mount Point
/dev/sda1      ext4             /
/dev/sda2      extended         
  /dev/sda5    linux-swap       
/dev/sda3      ext4             /development
/dev/sda4      ext4
```

`/dev/sda4` is a copy of `/dev/sda1`, just on a larger partition. I now want the `/dev/sda4` partition to be mounted at root (`/`) so that it is the default boot partition.

Finally a question - how can I change the `/dev/sda4` partition to be mounted at root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/fstab` should be modified with the entries for the new partition. It has parameters to define mountpoint and whether to be mounted automatically.

If you're looking for detailed explanations, look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions
https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-hdds-mount-at-startup-in-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the boot loader configuration. That is probably Grub or Grub2. There is a kernel parameter `root=...` with the device name, device ID, file system label or file system UUID. You have to change that to the new partition. On `/dev/sda4` you have to change the entry in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @travega I don't know Ubuntu 12.04. Somebody who knows could tell you in detail which distro tool to use. But if you want good answers you should get used to asking much better (=more precise) questions than "Can you elaborate?". This is a site for professionals and noone is going to read the manual to you. So tell what you have tried and what the problem is. `/etc/fstab` can be changed with every editor (but probably there is a distro tool for that).

Comment: I am full aware that this is a resource for professionals and as such expect answers to be of high quality not vague hints at what I need to look at. My OP couldn't be more concise. If your statement: "I don't know Ubuntu 12.04" is true then I would suggest perhaps you are not best qualified to answer the question.

Comment: @travega You expect from (unpaid) others but not from yourself. We love that kind here. Good luck with waiting for people who follow your attitude. Your statement does not even excuse your comment (which I referred to, not the OP). My hints were no vague guesses but a precise answer what to do. Just not **how** to do that. People who don't know how to edit `fstab` are not helped here but laughed at. Remember: Professionals. And if you want just the best qualified people to answer then mention that in your question to make sure those are not interested in helping you.

Comment: Wow you have a very elitist attitude toward this community. Fistly, I never said it was a guessed answer, I said it is vague, which it is. If I don't find your answer helpful I am allowed to ask if you have more information regardless of whether you are getting paid or not, that's how communities work... SE likes elitist less then it likes noobs good luck with your own attitude.

Comment: Please, let's keep it civil here guys - these posts are starting to gather mod flags. @travega - if you need clarification about a specific point, you're welcome to ask another question that focusses on the part you're having trouble with (e.g. if you can't find the `fstab` file or are having trouble editing it, then ask a specific question about that). @Hauke - no need to be snarky or to have a go at someone simply for asking for clarification.